# Whatsapp web does not accept jpg file in portrait orientation

Tags: web, jpeg, whatsapp, landscape, portrait

Using Whatsapp web on my PC, drag & drop jpg files to send them via Whatsapp. If the file is in portrait orientation, I get a message: ".file you tried adding is not supported 1".
If I rotate the file to landscape, Whatsapp web accepts it (but the pic is distorted and in the wrong orientation).
There is no problem with portrait images in the Whatsapp phone app.
Why doesn't Whatsapp web accept portrait pictures? Is there any workaround or manipulation of the portrait file that can cause Whatsapp web to accept it?

Comment: Did you try more than one browser?

Comment: Whatsapp-Web recommends chrome firefox or opera, I only have chrome installed, perhaps someone else can try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the photo in an editor (I used Picasa) and save a copy. The portrait photos from my Canon EOS camera are rejected by Whatsapp Web, but once I open and save them, everything was fine.

Do submit this as a bug with the Whatsapp devs, if you can.

Comment: Thanks, indeed saving a copy in Picasa is a valid workaround. (Saving a copy in Microsoft Gallery however, does not work). It seems Picasa changes some property of the jpg that Whatsapp Web does not accept.

Comment: Sent a bug report to whatsapp via their "Contact us" app feature

Comment: Got an answer from the whatsapp team today: "We are aware of the issue and we are working on fixing it in a future update of WhatsApp. Unfortunately, we cannot comment on any future release dates at this time."

Answer (score 2):

I saw this problem in Desktop app (windows).  Got it solved after restarting the application.

Comment: Just refreshing WhatsApp web solved my problem (Firefox on Linux).